# chromedriver session not created about webview in hybrid app

Tags: android, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, adb

Whenever I try to create session through chromedriver, it failed.
What I did is...

- run chromedriver.exe in local
- adb connect to device (I checked the connection with `adb devices`.)
- open app and navigate to webview page
- request POST method to create chromedriver session like below

**request**

```
POST http://localhost:9515/session
Body
{
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "androidActivity": "<MY_ACTIVITY_NAME>",
            "androidDeviceSerial": "<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>",
            "androidPackage": "<MY_APP_NAME>",
            "androidProcess": "<MY_APP_NAME>",
            "androidUseRunningApp": true,
            "w3c": true
         },
         "goog:loggingPrefs": {
            "browser": "ALL"
         }
      }
   }
}
HEADER
Content-Type: application/json
```

**response**

```
{
    "value": {
        "error": "session not created",
        "message": "session not created: please close 'com.android.chrome' and try again",
        "stacktrace": "0   chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a106d49 chromedriver_99 + 5111113\n1   chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a094d13 chromedriver_99 + 4644115\n2   chromedriver_99                     0x0000000109c86bb8 chromedriver_99 + 392120\n3   chromedriver_99                     0x0000000109cac7dd chromedriver_99 + 546781\n4   chromedriver_99                     0x0000000109ca59c9 chromedriver_99 + 518601\n5   chromedriver_99                     0x0000000109cdef4a chromedriver_99 + 753482\n6   chromedriver_99                     0x0000000109cd9103 chromedriver_99 + 729347\n7   chromedriver_99                     0x0000000109caf05d chromedriver_99 + 557149\n8   chromedriver_99                     0x0000000109cb0035 chromedriver_99 + 561205\n9   chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a0c411d chromedriver_99 + 4837661\n10  chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a0ddb4c chromedriver_99 + 4942668\n11  chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a0e3312 chromedriver_99 + 4965138\n12  chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a0de47a chromedriver_99 + 4945018\n13  chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a0b9310 chromedriver_99 + 4793104\n14  chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a0f8ae8 chromedriver_99 + 5053160\n15  chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a0f8c6f chromedriver_99 + 5053551\n16  chromedriver_99                     0x000000010a10df25 chromedriver_99 + 5140261\n17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2033b8fc _pthread_start + 224\n18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20337443 thread_start + 15\n"
    }
}
```

#### Error Reason?

I checked that chromedriver and remote browser (in webview) version is compatitable.

But, weird thing is chromedriver sends `killforward` command to adb. after that command, chromedriver received 'the adb init session request failed'.

In normal log, chromedriver doesn't send killforward command. why this chromedriver do this?

```
[1646997877.126][DEBUG]: Sending adb command: host-serial:<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>:killforward:tcp:64017
```

**chromedriver.log**

```
{
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "androidActivity": "<MY_ACTIVITY_NAME>",
            "androidDeviceSerial": "<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>",
            "androidPackage": "<MY_APP_NAME>",
            "androidProcess": "<MY_APP_NAME>",
            "androidUseRunningApp": true,
            "w3c": true
         },
         "goog:loggingPrefs": {
            "browser": "ALL"
         }
      }
   }
}
[1646997876.636][DEBUG]: Sending adb command: host:devices
[1646997876.637][DEBUG]: Received adb response: <MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>  device

[1646997876.637][DEBUG]: Sending adb command: host:transport:<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>|shell:pm path <MY_APP_NAME>
[1646997876.761][DEBUG]: Received adb response: package:/data/app/<MY_APP_NAME>-bYL5XjEmW2ih1Q6WgnQ6Tw==/base.apk

[1646997876.761][DEBUG]: Sending adb command: host:transport:<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>|shell:ps && ps -A
[1646997877.063][DEBUG]: Received adb response: USER           PID  PPID     VSZ    RSS WCHAN            ADDR S NAME                       
shell        30857  9646   33996   2268 sigsuspend 78274e6168 S sh
shell        30859 30857   36772   3052 0          738140ee48 R ps
USER           PID  PPID     VSZ    RSS WCHAN            ADDR S NAME                       
...            ...  ...      ...    ... ...               ... ... ...
u0_a248      25771  3843 2425944 352008 0                   0 S <MY_APP_NAME>


[1646997877.064][DEBUG]: Sending adb command: host:transport:<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>|shell:grep -a '@webview_devtools_remote_.*25771' /proc/net/unix
[1646997877.114][DEBUG]: Received adb response: 0000000000000000: 00000002 00000000 00010000 0001 01 13057474 @webview_devtools_remote_25771
0000000000000000: 00000003 00000000 00000000 0001 03 13101870 @webview_devtools_remote_25771
0000000000000000: 00000003 00000000 00000000 0001 03 13072544 @webview_devtools_remote_25771

[1646997877.114][DEBUG]: Sending adb command: host-serial:<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>:forward:tcp:0;localabstract:webview_devtools_remote_25771
[1646997877.115][DEBUG]: ADB server responded with "OKAYOKAY" instead of "OKAY".
[1646997877.115][DEBUG]: Received adb response: 64017
[1646997877.115][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:64017/json/version
[1646997877.126][DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Response: {
   "Android-Package": "com.android.chrome",
   "Browser": "Chrome/99.0.4844.58",
   "Protocol-Version": "1.3",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-A305N Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/99.0.4844.58 Mobile Safari/537.36",
   "V8-Version": "9.9.115.8",
   "WebKit-Version": "537.36 (@15ccad7c5507e806397e06a31ab918e52bb47b22)",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:64017/devtools/browser"
}

[1646997877.126][DEBUG]: Sending adb command: host-serial:<MY_DEVICE_SERIAL>:killforward:tcp:64017
[1646997877.126][DEBUG]: ADB server responded with "OKAYOKAY" instead of "OKAY".
[1646997877.126][DEBUG]: Received adb response: 
[1646997877.126][INFO]: [f0ef9b7bde72b0cc8e5a4729ffee085f] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR session not created: please close 'com.android.chrome' and try again
[1646997877.126][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[1646997877.126][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

please help me... automation masters...

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause in [chromedriver code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/).
If the android pakcage name of the devtools client's browser_info doesn't match with android package name of capabilities option, then it throws session not created error.
But, I don't know why the devtools parse the android package as empty string.

```
  const BrowserInfo* browser_info = client->browser_info();
  std::cout("%s", browser_info->android_package.c_str())
  if (browser_info->is_android &&
    browser_info->android_package != capabilities->android_package) {
    return Status(
      kSessionNotCreated,
      base::StringPrintf("please close '%s' and try again",
                          browser_info->android_package.c_str()));
  }
```

Comment: I found the reason why devtools parse the android package as empty string. The getPackageName method had been override. 
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/refs/heads/main/android/java/src/org/chromium/base/BuildInfo.java

Comment: Any solution/workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Based on investigation of @roseline I have found a capability of the android driver:

```
caps.setCapability("extractChromeAndroidPackageFromContextName", true);
```